# Show/Hide text from a list of contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to keep a static list of contents (around 10 bullet points) that will show and hide text when each different heading/title is clicked. I can kind of get there but I think i'm taking the long way since i'm unfamiliar with JS.

Wondering if someone can show me a better/easier way to do this because my JS looks absolutely silly and i'd have to repeat it **a lot** for my method.

Side note: for some reason i need to click the title/header twice for the JS to work

```js
function pointOne() {
  var x = document.getElementById("contentOne");
  var y = document.getElementById("firstText");
  var z = document.getElementById("contentTwo");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function pointTwo() {
    var x = document.getElementById("contentTwo");
    var y = document.getElementById("firstText");
    var z = document.getElementById("contentOne");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
      y.style.display = "none";
      z.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
      y.style.display = "none";
      z.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```css
#contentOne, #contentTwo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div style="background-color: #eee; padding: 10px;">
      <div id="firstText">
        <p>A welcoming text blurb here</p>
      </div>
      <div id="contentOne">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">1. Title number one</span></strong></span></p><p>Text blurb of title 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="contentTwo">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">2. Title number two</span></strong></span></p><p>Text blurb of title 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div>
          <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;color: #ccc">Table Of Contents</span></strong></span></p><p>
        <a href="#point1" onclick="pointOne()">1. Title 1 to click</a><br><br>
        <a href="#point2" onclick="pointTwo()">2. Title 2 to click</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: So you are trying to show a specific section when someone clicks a link in the table of contents, and hide all the other sections, correct?

Comment: @GhostPengy that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a function that works for all points by passing an argument with the element itself.
This should make it much easier to add new elements since you dont have to write any new functions

In the button you can add a data-contentId tag to set the content id and access it in js:

```js
function point(button) {
  //var x = document.getElementById("contentOne");
  //var y = document.getElementById("firstText");
  //var z = document.getElementById("contentTwo"); 
  const content = document.getElementById(button.dataset.contentid);
  //console.log(content.style);
  const display = getComputedStyle(content)["display"];
  const container = button.parentElement.children;
  const firstText = document.getElementById("firstText");
  let contents
  for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
  contents = container[i].dataset.contentid;
  if(contents) /*in case its a br element*/  document.getElementById(container[i].dataset.contentid).style.display="none";
}
  if(display === "none"){
    content.style.display = "block";
    firstText.style.display = "none";
  }else{
  content.style.display = "none";
  firstText.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#contentOne, #contentTwo {
  display: none;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <div style="background-color: #eee; padding: 10px;">
      <div id="firstText">
        <p>A welcoming text blurb here</p>
      </div>
      <div id="contentOne" class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">1. Title number one</span></strong></span></p><p>Text blurb of title 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="contentTwo"class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">2. Title number two</span></strong></span></p><p>Text blurb of title 2
        </p>
      </div>
        <div id="content3"class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">An example</span></strong></span></p><p>Text blurb of title 3
        </p>
      </div>      
      <div id="content4"class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">It works</span></strong></span></p><p>Yh it does
        </p>
      </div>      
      <div id="content5"class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">Another one</span></strong></span></p><p>Epic
        </p>
      </div>      
      <div id="content6"class="content">
        <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">Its much easier instead of writing separate functiones</span></strong></span></p><p>Ofc it is
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div>
          <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;color: #ccc">Table Of Contents</span></strong></span></p>
        <div>
        <a data-contentId="contentOne" href="#point1" onclick="point(this)">1. Title 1 to click</a><br><br>
        <a data-contentId="contentTwo" href="#point2" onclick="point(this)">2. Title 2 to click</a><br><br>
        <a data-contentId="content3" href="#point2" onclick="point(this)">3. Title 2 to click</a><br><br>
        <a data-contentId="content4" href="#point2" onclick="point(this)">4. Title 2 to click</a><br><br>
        <a data-contentId="content5" href="#point2" onclick="point(this)">5. Title 2 to click</a><br><br>
        <a data-contentId="content6" href="#point2" onclick="point(this)">6. Title 2 to click</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A much more refined option would be to use only one content element and changing its contents with the javascript, how the answer from @Abdul Aziz Sapra works. I made this one to be similar to your original code.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is way easier to manipulate existing dom than changing contents. Since that content needs to be somewhere already, why not where it is expected to be and then altar state of it. As per mentioned example, you cannot include HTML and other dom elements that way.

Comment: This is perfect for me. Especially for what @GhostPengy mentioned which is what i need to include. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to repeat yourself multiple times while coding, its never a good sign.

I am not sure what you intend to do, but **if you can**, I would suggest to use Bootstrap to make your life **a lot** easier. Using Bootstrap you could use "Collapse" to achieve your goal. Here's how to do it: [Bootstrap Collapse Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/)

If you are unfamiliar with Bootstrap, you find good help [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Since you need list-items instead of buttons in the Collapse example, collapse should also work with other html tags than just buttons.

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't posted your complete scenario, there could be a number of solutions. I am posting only one, let me know if this helps you or you are trying to do something else. If you are trying to do something else do let me know as well. But I think this code will help you understand how you can make your functions re-useable Happy Coding :)

```
<div style="background-color: #eee; padding: 10px;">
  <div>
    <p>A welcoming text blurb here</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>
      <span style="font-size: 20pt;">
        <strong>
          <span id="main_content_heading_area"
            style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;">1. Title
            number
            one</span>
        </strong>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p id="blurb_content_heading_area">
      Text blurb of title 1
    </p>
  </div>



</div>


<div>
  <p><span style="font-size: 20pt;"><strong><span
          style="font-family: Helvetica Neue Condensed,Helvetica Neueu,helvetica,sans-serif;color: #ccc">Table Of
          Contents</span></strong></span></p>
  <p>
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleContentOnButtonClick('1. Title number one','Text blurb of title 1')">1.
      Title 1
      to
      click</a><br><br>
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggleContentOnButtonClick('2. Title number two','Text blurb of title 2')">2.
      Title 2
      to click</a>
  </p>
</div>


<script>



  function toggleContentOnButtonClick(heading, sub_heading) {
    document.querySelector("#main_content_heading_area").innerHTML = heading;
    document.querySelector("#blurb_content_heading_area").innerHTML = sub_heading;

  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is working for me. So thank you! However, is there a way that the 'welcoming text blurb' displays on first load like it does now, but once you start clicking the headers it goes away?

Comment: @Brandon you can add a state for that heading area

Comment: @FurrySenko told you the correct way. You can implement it after learning some basics of javascript.

Comment: @Kiran Maniya thanks for removing the extra spaces from my code. :P